# Title Custom Blocks - Customize TITLE of text fragments!

Tags: titles, article, section-titles, customize, custom

I use LaTeX but at some ways I'm still quite inexperienced.

When building a class, and would like to leave a few highlights items, like the ones below.

[image: Assimilate]

[image: Reflects]

[image: Example]

[image: Search]

If they could help me I'll be very grateful;

So I thank you, in advance, for your help.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the title text is longer than one line? And do you want it implemented as a sectional command (like \section, \subsection, etc)? What is the nature of these "text fragments"?

Comment: Are highlights in a worKbook. 

There is no need for a section, subsection or the like.

Can make use of tiks and tcolorbox.

@PeterFlynn

Comment: It's also possible just using graphicx, xcolor, careful positioning, and some symbols from (eg) marvosym.